# Power Apps Embed Canvas App into a model driven app and give data through

Tags: canvas, model, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-modeldriven

I have a model driven app with some data in tables. If i choose a certain row, it opens a new form where I can edit this data. In the same form I have embedded a canvas app. This canvas app contains a pdf viewer. Now I want to "connect" the canvas app with the model driven app, so that the pdf viewer in the canvas app shows me the pdf from the data which is selected in the model driven app.

How can I "passtrough" the selected data into the canvas app? And how can I set the "Document" function in the pdf viewer of the canvas app with a "placeholder"?

Comment: I just got the same issue now. I can get my canvas app with pdf viewer to work normally but inside a model-driven app form, the pdf is not shown.

Firstly, you need to have the ModelDrivenFormIntegration control setup in your canvas app.